# Credit Risk Analysis_Feature selection_Duplicate values in Information Value and weight of evidence table python

Tags: python, pandas, finance, risk-analysis

**WOE and IV** are important concepts in credit risk analysis used to find out **features which are relevant to predict** whether or not a person is a possible **loan** **defaulter**. Lets say I have a person with some variables (could be age, income, past credit score etc., and I need to predict based on past data which ppl are likely to default. Now I have 1000 variables. All the variables will not be of equal importance while predicting loan default. So WOE and IV help me in finding out which variable out of all the variables should I use in any model. Below is a sample df and a generic function to find WOE and IV for any df. My doubt is stated below.

**X_train** (independent variables in credit risk analysis)

```
Var1  Var2     .............  Var1000
30     Unknown .............  80000
33     Success .............   90000
45     Failure .............     899900
```

**y_train** (dependent variable in credit risk analysis to denote customer default or not in a loan)

```
0
1
0
0...and so on
```

**Code to find the most relevant and important variables from a dataframe (WOE and IV)**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.core.algorithms as algos
from pandas import Series
import scipy.stats.stats as stats
import re
import traceback
import string

max_bin = 20
force_bin = 3

# define a binning function
def mono_bin(Y, X, n = max_bin):

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": X, "Y": Y})
    justmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.isnull()]
    notmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.notnull()]
    r = 0
    while np.abs(r) < 1:
        try:
            d1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": notmiss.X, "Y": notmiss.Y, "Bucket": pd.qcut(notmiss.X, n)})
            d2 = d1.groupby('Bucket', as_index=True)
            r, p = stats.spearmanr(d2.mean().X, d2.mean().Y)
            n = n - 1 
        except Exception as e:
            n = n - 1

    if len(d2) == 1:
        n = force_bin         
        bins = algos.quantile(notmiss.X, np.linspace(0, 1, n))
        if len(np.unique(bins)) == 2:
            bins = np.insert(bins, 0, 1)
            bins[1] = bins[1]-(bins[1]/2)
        d1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": notmiss.X, "Y": notmiss.Y, "Bucket": pd.cut(notmiss.X, np.unique(bins),include_lowest=True)}) 
        d2 = d1.groupby('Bucket', as_index=True)

    d3 = pd.DataFrame({},index=[])
    d3["MIN_VALUE"] = d2.min().X
    d3["MAX_VALUE"] = d2.max().X
    d3["COUNT"] = d2.count().Y
    d3["EVENT"] = d2.sum().Y
    d3["NONEVENT"] = d2.count().Y - d2.sum().Y
    d3=d3.reset_index(drop=True)

    if len(justmiss.index) > 0:
        d4 = pd.DataFrame({'MIN_VALUE':np.nan},index=[0])
        d4["MAX_VALUE"] = np.nan
        d4["COUNT"] = justmiss.count().Y
        d4["EVENT"] = justmiss.sum().Y
        d4["NONEVENT"] = justmiss.count().Y - justmiss.sum().Y
        d3 = d3.append(d4,ignore_index=True)

    d3["EVENT_RATE"] = d3.EVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["NON_EVENT_RATE"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["DIST_EVENT"] = d3.EVENT/d3.sum().EVENT
    d3["DIST_NON_EVENT"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.sum().NONEVENT
    d3["WOE"] = np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["IV"] = (d3.DIST_EVENT-d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)*np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["VAR_NAME"] = "VAR"
    d3 = d3[['VAR_NAME','MIN_VALUE', 'MAX_VALUE', 'COUNT', 'EVENT', 'EVENT_RATE', 'NONEVENT', 'NON_EVENT_RATE', 'DIST_EVENT','DIST_NON_EVENT','WOE', 'IV']]       
    d3 = d3.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
    d3.IV = d3.IV.sum()

    return(d3)

def char_bin(Y, X):

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": X, "Y": Y})
    justmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.isnull()]
    notmiss = df1[['X','Y']][df1.X.notnull()]    
    df2 = notmiss.groupby('X',as_index=True)

    d3 = pd.DataFrame({},index=[])
    d3["COUNT"] = df2.count().Y
    d3["MIN_VALUE"] = df2.sum().Y.index
    d3["MAX_VALUE"] = d3["MIN_VALUE"]
    d3["EVENT"] = df2.sum().Y
    d3["NONEVENT"] = df2.count().Y - df2.sum().Y

    if len(justmiss.index) > 0:
        d4 = pd.DataFrame({'MIN_VALUE':np.nan},index=[0])
        d4["MAX_VALUE"] = np.nan
        d4["COUNT"] = justmiss.count().Y
        d4["EVENT"] = justmiss.sum().Y
        d4["NONEVENT"] = justmiss.count().Y - justmiss.sum().Y
        d3 = d3.append(d4,ignore_index=True)

    d3["EVENT_RATE"] = d3.EVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["NON_EVENT_RATE"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.COUNT
    d3["DIST_EVENT"] = d3.EVENT/d3.sum().EVENT
    d3["DIST_NON_EVENT"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.sum().NONEVENT
    d3["WOE"] = np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["IV"] = (d3.DIST_EVENT-d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)*np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
    d3["VAR_NAME"] = "VAR"
    d3 = d3[['VAR_NAME','MIN_VALUE', 'MAX_VALUE', 'COUNT', 'EVENT', 'EVENT_RATE', 'NONEVENT', 'NON_EVENT_RATE', 'DIST_EVENT','DIST_NON_EVENT','WOE', 'IV']]      
    d3 = d3.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
    d3.IV = d3.IV.sum()
    d3 = d3.reset_index(drop=True)

    return(d3)

def data_vars(df1, target):

    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    filename, lineno, function_name, code = stack[-2]
    vars_name = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\).*$').search(code).groups()[0]
    final = (re.findall(r"[\w']+", vars_name))[-1]

    x = df1.dtypes.index
    count = -1

    for i in x:
        if i.upper() not in (final.upper()):
            if np.issubdtype(df1[i], np.number) and len(Series.unique(df1[i])) > 2:
                conv = mono_bin(target, df1[i])
                conv["VAR_NAME"] = i
                count = count + 1
            else:
                conv = char_bin(target, df1[i])
                conv["VAR_NAME"] = i            
                count = count + 1

            if count == 0:
                iv_df = conv
            else:
                iv_df = iv_df.append(conv,ignore_index=True)

    iv = pd.DataFrame({'IV':iv_df.groupby('VAR_NAME').IV.max()})
    iv = iv.reset_index()
    return(iv_df,iv)
```

**Calling function**

```
    final_iv, IV = data_vars(X_train, y_train)
```

**Output**

```
VAR_NAME    MIN_VALUE   MAX_VALUE   COUNT   EVENT   EVENT_RATE  NONEVENT    NON_EVENT_RATE  DIST_EVENT  DIST_NON_EVENT   WOE           IV
0   Var1    19          39        2290   259     0.113100     2031         0.886900      0.497121   0.50775         -0.021156   0.000452
1   Var1    40          87          2231     262     0.117436     1969         0.882564      0.502879   0.49225         0.021363     0.000452
64  Var2    failure     failure        490   63      0.128571     427          0.871429      0.120921   0.10675         0.124650    0.461890
65  Var2    other       other          197  38       0.192893      159          0.807107     0.072937   0.03975         0.606982    0.461890
66  Var2   success      success        129  83       0.643411       46           0.356589   0.159309    0.01150          2.628499   0.461890
67  Var2    unknown     unknown        3705 337      0.090958      3368         0.909042    0.646833    0.84200          -0.263692  0.461890
```

and so on....

If you see there are 2 values for the same variable `Var1` and 4 values for `Var2` variable. I am unable to understand what is the meaning of multiple rows for the same variable.
What is this function data_vars trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are binned, probably under the assumption that some features can have different WOE/IV scores across their distribution. For example, Var1 has different WOE scores for [19,39] than [40,87]. Whether this binning makes sense for categorical variables, like Var2, is a different story.